Wordpress database size limit has exceed
I have database on Hpanel and its limit has been exceed I have try to repair and optimize but it was not helpful enter image description here
I have tried to repair and optimize the database also clear the cache and i want to reduce the size of database

If you're facing the "WordPress database size limit has exceeded" issue on hPanel, start by checking your database size in phpMyAdmin to identify large tables. Optimize the database by cleaning up expired transients, deleting spam comments, clearing post revisions, and removing unnecessary logs using plugins like WP-Optimize or WP-Sweep. Empty the trash for posts and comments, and deactivate unused plugins to free up space. To prevent future issues, limit post revisions by adding define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 5); to your wp-config.php file and schedule regular database cleanups. If the database is still too large, consider upgrading your hosting plan for more space.

the table named "wp_postmeta" size is approx 4GB how can i reduced it

From your comments it sounds like you have a lot of content in the database, so try to break it down and see what kind of content you have and if it is still relevant.
Starting with wp_posts table, check what kind of content you have (we start with wp_posts, because you've indicated postmeta table is 4gb):
select distinct(post_type), count(ID) AS total from wp_posts GROUP BY post_type ORDER by total DESC;
You might find that there are post types with posts from plugins you no longer use, e.g. acf-field and acf (ACF plugin). Don't rush to delete them, because data will be stored in postmeta table and linked through wp_postmeta.post_id to ID in wp_posts table.
Typically, one post stored in wp_posts table does not have a lot of post meta table entries, so you should start with post types that have the most posts. You can check number of post meta entries, and get approximate size in KB running these queries:
select count(*) from wp_postmeta AS pm LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS p ON pm.post_id = p.ID WHERE p.post_type='post'
select ROUND(SUM(LENGTH(meta_value))/ 1024) AS size_in_kb from wp_postmeta AS pm LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS p ON pm.post_id = p.ID WHERE p.post_type='post';
If you are running WooCommerce, you might want to migrate orders to HPOS tables if you haven't done so.
All things said, you probably want to look at upgrading your hosting plan or look for alternative hosting provider because it's very likely that your database size increases due to activity on site (new blog posts, products or orders).

Get the backup of db and delete unnecessary and cache data.

its the 6GB database size

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
